# How can I get ID, name and all the stats for Channel in YouTube using their APIs

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-channels

I'm a new developer not any experience with APIs. What I have to do is that I have an app. A chrome extension which gets attached to YouTube. Now what I want to achieve is that whenever I open a channel in YouTube I should get all the stats of that Channel.

I have to get the channel ID, channel name, other stats like the number of views of the channel, likes and comments of the channel. And after getting those values I have to display the channel name and all the stats I mentioned.

So how can I achieve this task.

Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: show us some code, what did you tried ?

Comment: stackoverflow is not a factory of ready made solution, check the api, the code example provide in the api doc.

Comment: Why don't you start with the YouTube API? https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

Answer (score 5):

First of all you need the channel's ID. If you want to access the datas via channel's urlname (Example : www.youtube.com/user/CHANNEL_URLNAME) first use this api to get the channel id.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&forUsername=CHANNEL_URLNAME&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Then use that ID to get channel's data and stats.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet,statistics&id=CHANNEL_ID&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

Notice that the `part` parameter takes the name of the datas you want to retrieve. `snippet` will give you datas like channel's title, it's logo, description etc. while `statistics` will help you retrieve the datas like total views, subscribers count etc.

You can also look at this link for other information that you can retrieve from the API.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list

Note: If you see a "channel" segment on a youtube channels url the last part would be the channel's ID so you wouldn't need to use the first API call to get the channel's ID. (Example: youtube/channel/CHANNEL_ID).